# Menu that appears from above and below hides and shows on screen touch in android without using the menu button

Tags: android

Is it possible to create a menu in android that shows when someone for example touches a graph and It brings more options. I want a menu that will appear from above and below like how the menu used to be in android when you touch the menu button. Now without the button i would like the user to touch a chart or a table and two menus appear from above and below or even sides. Any suggestions will highly be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Suggestion:
Make the layout of menu you would like to show, and include it in the layout of your activity.
By default set it to be GONE, this will hide it.
Then set a touch listener for your graph, and change the visibility of menu to VISIBLE to show it.

Answer (score 0):

I think what u need is a context menu; see [this example](http://moorandroid.blogspot.in/p/context-menu.html) Hope this helps :) cheers :)